# Having trouble with multiple JOIN tables and WHERE AND

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have been doing good in my SQL class, but for whatever reason, I'm still having trouble understanding how to use JOIN with WHERE and AND.

My question that I need help on is:
Write a SELECT statement that displays two columns – bowler id, first name, last name, and raw score. You must use table join. Include the bowlers who had a raw score of 175 or better at Imperial Lanes. Use proper column headings. Sort the results by raw score in descending order.

My code is:

```
SELECT bowlerid || ' ' || b.bowlerfirstname || ' ' || b.bowlerlastname "Bowler",
      bs.rawscore "Raw Score"
  FROM bowlers b JOIN bowler_scores bs USING (bowlerid)
      JOIN tourney_matches tm USING (matchid)
      JOIN tournaments USING (tourneyid)
  WHERE bs.rawscore >= 175
    AND tourneylocation = 'Imperial Lanes'
  ORDER BY "Raw Score" DESC;
```

I'm not sure if I'm joining the tables correctly, as my results are not correct.

**Tables** - Columns

**bowler_scores** - matchid, gamenumber, bowlerid, rawscore

**bowlers** - bowlerid, bowlerlastname, bowlerfirstname, teamid

**match_games** - matchid, gamenumber, winningteamid

**tournaments** - tourneyid, tourneydate, tourneylocation

**tourney_matches** - matchid, tourneyid

I left some columns out as they are not needed for the code.

I added the actual database code in links 3 & 4.

[This is what I should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr8ej.png)

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eoLX.png)

[Data code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nqhrhn9rgh364r/BowlingLeagueData.txt?dl=0)

[Structure code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ql1mztolnv97cet/BowlingLeagueStructure.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the expected output and what you are actually getting?

Comment: I'm lost at the "two columns – bowler id, first name, last name, and raw score.".

Comment: Just updated the post to include the expected outcome

Comment: Would also please include the result that you are currently getting, and the corresponding sample data ?

Comment: I added a sample of what I'm getting and also added links for text files with the entire code data and structure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whoever made the original example posted the incorrect outcome, which is why I was thinking my output was incorrect. After cross-checking the actual data, I came to the conclusion that my code is correct.

```
SELECT bowlerid || ' ' || bowlerfirstname || ' ' || bowlerlastname "Bowler",
    rawscore "Raw Score"
  FROM tournaments JOIN tourney_matches USING (tourneyid)
    JOIN bowler_scores USING (matchid)
    JOIN bowlers USING (bowlerid)
  WHERE rawscore >= 175    
    AND tourneylocation = 'Imperial Lanes'
  ORDER BY "Raw Score" DESC;
```